# I'm stuck on a level in Think Different for android

Tags: think-different

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKSzV.jpg) is the level that I'm stuck on:

```
42  15  14
56  35  8
36  ??  4
```

I've spent a considerable amount of time on this level, but still can not figure it out.

Comment: Since it's probably a 2 digit number and you've spent 44 hours on it, wouldn't it be easier to just guess every number from 1-100?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is **45**.

---

## Here's how you solve it:

To get the numbers in the first column, take the number in the third column and solve, eg. `42 = 14 * x`, therefore `x = 3`. Multiply this number by y to get the 2nd column number. eg. `15 = y * 3` this yields `y = 5`.

First row:

`42 = 14 * 3`, `15 = 5 * 3`

Do this for the second row as well:

`56 = 8 * 7`, `35 = 5 * 7`

See that `y` is always 5 so for the third row find the x as per the previous two then use `y = 5` to solve `??`:

`36 = 4 * 9`, so `??` must be `5 * 9` ie. `45`

Comment: Ah I was close to this logic, but I didn't work out how to get the 5, and I also thought that it would be less than 36 like the previous two so I thought it might've been `3*9`. But this logic makes sense. Good job

Comment: @Aequitas, if you think OP has not done a good job formatting his answer, dont keep changing it around. Post your own answer, instead of branching across the implications of author intent.

Comment: Reverting back to oroginal answer to retain authors intent. As per [meta on updating out of date answers](http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/10765/updating-an-out-of-date-answer-versus-keeping-author-intent), even in the case of out of date answers, we are promoted to leave the original and post our own versions. OPs version had nothing wrong with it, apart from the lack of answer. Adding alternate format neither adds useful information.

Comment: Note that OP will denote permission to make aesthetic changes by posting a "community wiki" answer.

Comment: Format changes are perfectly valid edits. Things do not need to be made Community Wiki for such edits to be allowed. That said, if the argument is whether or not this particular format change actually improved the answer, that's one thing. But if the argument is that format changes shouldn't be made in the first place, that's not correct.

Comment: @Sterno, format questions are promptly canned in the review queue as "no improvement". Do you have meta backing you up, or are you making assumptions?

Comment: @Timelord64 If the edits improve the post and make it easier to read or understand, they should be considered improvements.

Comment: @Timelord64 I was going by the [help for the site](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/editing). Specifically, under the "When should I edit posts?" section, the part that says "To clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning)". That's certainly what Aequitas was attempting here. Again, though, I can see an argument for whether or not clarification was actually accomplished.

Comment: @Sterno, that is my point. It was not, really. Aequitas took the answer from my post, and added it this post, after previously suggesting a completely different answer entirely.